# Problem with dual-booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, ahci, rst

Some weeks ago I bought a new Lenovo IdeaPad S540 laptop with Intel RST controller mode by default. When I tried to dual-boot Windows, which was installed earlier with Ubuntu 20.04, I got a window that I mustn't use RST. I searched for this question, tried to change the mode to AHCI with Safe Mode in Windows. But I got such warning:
[image]

I am a newbie in Linux, so sorry for silly questions. Maybe this is a part of the usual setup procedure. I hope you can help me.

Computer species:

- Intel Core i5-8265U
- Intel UHD 620
- NVMe SSD Samsung 512GB (Non-RAID)
- 8GB RAM

Thanks all

Comment: Like it says, it will probably delete everything so you should have backups and a windows system backup too. Most people don't run into that issue.

Comment: Backup always good idea before any system change. But have not seen any user post that or have issue of erased Windows from just the change to AHCI. But you must install AHCI drivers into Windows first.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi